# How to fix error of type "object of type 'CategoricalDtype' has no len()"?

Tags: python, machine-learning

In training data: the datatype of x is "int64" and y is "categorical"
I can't able to fit training data-set in this algorithm..

i am getting an error in the line "model.fit(x_train,y_train)"

the error is "object of type 'CategoricalDtype' has no len()"

```
    x=df.drop("income",axis=1)
    y=df["income"]
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split         
    x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,train_size=0.3,random_state=100)
    from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
    model=DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=4)
    model.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

Comment: Please post the full error trace, as well as a sample of your data

Answer (score 1):

try to add `.tolist()` after `y_train and y_test`